# Why is "Selected Graphics (Clipping)" always grayed-out in Export Raster Data?

Tags: raster, arcmap, data, export

I would like to utilize the "Selected Graphics (Clipping) option so I may export my raster data along the boundaries of a polygon mask which I created earlier.

I would use "Selected Graphics (Clipping) to do this, however it is always grayed out.

Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right.  The feature is active only after drawing a graphic feature polygon.  Thank you.  I will move on and use the clip tool.  To anyone else who wants to know more about drawing graphic features follow this url: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/adding-and-modifying-graphics-adding-a-graphic.htm

Comment: Most welcome, will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post on the esri forum](https://community.esri.com/thread/186532-selected-graphics-clipping-throw-export-mosaic-data-set) (*which I slightly edited for readability*):

> Selected Graphics (clipping) that you refer in the picture, it is active if you are draw any graphic feature (polygon) not feature class or shape file.
>   But if you want to clip raster with a shape file or feature class. you can use:
>
> 1-Clip [(Clip—Help | ArcGIS for Desktop )](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm)
>
> or
>
> 2-Extract by Mask [(Extract by Mask—Help | ArcGIS for Desktop )](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm)